# How can i set proxy server with symfony/panther

Tags: php, web-scraping, proxy, symfony-panther

I found two way of setting proxy server one is through chrome web driver capabilities and the other one is directly setting while creating chrome client

```
$this->client = Client::createChromeClient(null, [
            '--proxy-server=socks://196.14.52.63:35048',
            '--headless',
            "--disable-gpu",
]);
```

but after setting proxy IP and port I get following error:

```
Curl error thrown for http POST to /session/cce06908d68a1e96bc6d1cb3b798aa14/url with params: {"url":"https:\/\/some-site\/login"}\n
Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

Basically I want to use proxy servers while **scraping** data using Symfony panther.

Comment: Did you make absolutely sure your proxy works with this config, e.g. by configuring it in a browser and trying manually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i made it work with passing following configuration.

```php
$this->client = Client::createChromeClient(null, [
            '--window-size=1200,1100',
            "--proxy-server=http://ip:port",
            '--headless',
            "--disable-gpu",
]);
```

i think previously proxy server i was using doesn't support https (i was try to visit https page) and i was also missing windows-size argument.

Answer (score 0):

Some times a proxy can take a long time to respond and the site you are trying to reach may be taking longer than 30sec. You can try increasing your time out like this:

```
Client::createChromeClient(base_path('drivers/chromedriver'), $args, ["port" => 9080, 'request_timeout_in_ms' => 100000]);
```