# Change user-agent for Symfony Panther Chromeclient

Tags: symfony, google-chrome, user-agent, symfony-panther

How do I change the user-agent in a headless Chrome created by Symfony's Panther `createChromeClient()`?

When I create a Chrome client with

`$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient();`

I see in the access_log a user-agent of

`"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36"`

I searched for solutions, and think I have to change the user-agent string via the arguments of the chrome, but can't find the right way, because the answers on the web aren't for PHP or Panther.

Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it:

```
$client = \Symfony\Component\Panther\Client::createChromeClient(null, [
            '--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36',
            '--window-size=1200,1100',
            '--headless',
            '--disable-gpu',
]);
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583732/how-can-i-set-proxy-server-with-symfony-panther/59599763#59599763) gave me the idea.