# Headless chrome with proxy

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

I am using symphony/panther php package to scrap the dynamic content of the page, it's working fine without proxy, but when I apply proxy it returns empty. I am not getting any error in the error log and in the browser.

I am using http/https proxy from here to test - https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list

Please have a look in the following code -

```
use Symfony\Component\Panther\Client;

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer's autoloader

$client = Client::createChromeClient(null,[
    '--proxy-server=http://ip:port',
    '--headless'
],
[
    'capabilities' => [
        'acceptInsecureCerts' => true
    ]
]);

$client->request('GET', 'http://example.com');

$html = $client->getInternalResponse()->getContent();

echo $html;
```

anything missing in the code? [I am using php 8.2.4]

Comment: Have you tried a bunch of proxies, and have you tried increasing the timeout to a large number?

Comment: yes @Chris, I've tried many proxies with max timeout, but it's not working with any proxy

Comment: Did you get a solution with chrome.  Firefox is an option but I'd like to get Chrome working.  Also see this ?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583732/how-can-i-set-proxy-server-with-symfony-panther

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is not allowing the proxy, use Client::createFirefoxClient instead Client::createChromeClient